# Is it possible to get ONLY the original results from an elasticsearch query without elastic-added json

Tags: elasticsearch

As the title suggests, I'm wondering if anyone is aware of a way to retrieve *just* the results of the query in a returned JSON array (that is: the data exactly as it was when written to the index).
i.e. instead of getting:

```
{
   "hits": {
      "total": {
         "value": 3
      },
      "hits": [
         {
            "_source": {
               "name": "name1",
               "mydata": {
                  "data-stuff1": "stuff1 etc"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "_source": {
               "name": "name2",
               "mydata": {
                  "data-stuff2": "stuff2 etc"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "_source": {
               "name": "name3",
               "mydata": {
                  "data-stuff3": "stuff3 etc"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

To receive *only* the data itself:

```
[
    {
       "data": {
          "data-stuff1": "stuff1 etc"
       }
    },
    {
       "data": {
          "data-stuff2": "stuff2 etc"
       }
    },
    {
       "data": {
          "data-stuff3": "stuff3 etc"
       }
    }
]
```

(i.e. with no hits.hits but more importantly, no '_source' wrapper for each element)

Of course, if there was an error, would need to check for that, or even have elastic include its meta data ...the main objective of this question is having an array of pure results as they were when written, not polluted with _source.

As _source is added by elastic, it would be quite nice if elastic could [optionally] not include it in results.

The above example included ?filter_path=hits.total.value,hits.hits._source parameters in the query, but this just removes the metadata objects (which can be useful).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `fields` parameter instead of the `_source` parameter in your query. The `fields` parameter allows you to specify which fields you want to retrieve from the index. By default, Elasticsearch includes the `_source` field in the response, but if you specify the fields explicitly, it will exclude the `_source` field.

Example query would be:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "fields": ["data-stuff"]
}
```

Comment: That will exclude the `_source` but introduce another wrapper called `fields`

Comment: @Val hmm, I see. And if you combine that with using `filter_path`?

Comment: What the OP wants is not possible. He needs to filter that himself on the client side. It's really pure cosmetics, though

Comment: Thanks for your responses!
Yes, I looked at fields but it moves the problem sideways :-)

The thing about 'cosmetics' is this is data, not human-viewable stuff (in this scenario), and when I'm retrieving say 10,000 elements, then need to iterate through each one to put it back into the original format, it can consume vast amounts of RAM/CPU time - it's less than ideal.

Thanks for confirming this isn't possible with elastic (although it is with Solr...)
I suppose I can just be happy it's not SQL! lol